# $d_1 = 5\hat{i} - 2\hat{j} + 4\hat{k}, d_2 = -5\hat{i} + 2\hat{j} -\hat{k}.$ What is $(d_1 + d_2)\cdot(d_1 · 2 d_2)$?

Tags: physics

$$\begin{align}
d_1 & = \;\;\;5\hat{i} - 2\hat{j} + 4\hat{k}\\
d_2 &= -5\hat{i} + 2\hat{j} - \hat{k}
\end{align}$$

What is $(d_1 + d_2)\cdot(d_1 · 2 d_2)$?

For some reason the homework problem needs an exact number answer already. When I solved it out I got $-150\hat{j} + 50\hat{i} \ldots$ I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Someone please help!

Comment: To see what you are doing wrong, what is $2i\cdot3j$?

Comment: 6k? I tried doing the vector and I got an answer in terms of i j and k. I dont know why the homework assigbment requires a regular number..

Comment: I think the $\cdot$ here is the [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) (or dot product) and not the [exterior product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra). In my example the answer is 6.

Comment: I still have no idea where to even begin with this problem though.